# Adding Rules to Topology with Arcpy: getting ERROR 000714

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, arcpy, topology

I want to make a very basic python script, however I keep running into error 000714 (general/unknown script error).

The topology is created, the features are added to it, however the rule is not. I've tried different rules, same problem; I will want to add more rules and validation if this error is overcome.

I have tried doing the same process in modelbuilder but the I get error 999999, the syntax is the same when I export the code from it.

Anyone run into this problem or find solution? I am using ArcGIS 10.1.

Code (The script tool's only parameter is a Dataset):

```
import arcpy, sys
from arcpy import env

env.workspace = sys.argv[1]

topolo = "GBA_Topology"

transLn = "TRANSPORT_LINE"
gbaTransLn = "GBA_TRANSPORT_LINES"

if arcpy.Exists(topolo):
    arcpy.Delete_management(topolo)

arcpy.CreateTopology_management(env.workspace, topolo, "0.001")

arcpy.AddFeatureClassToTopology_management(topolo, transLn, "5", "1")
arcpy.AddFeatureClassToTopology_management(topolo, gbaTransLn, "5", "1")

arcpy.AddRuleToTopology_management(topolo, "Must Not Self-Intersect (Line)", transLn, "", "", "")
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe your error might be that you are not properly referencing the topology after you create it. The following is adopted from a script I wrote; you might want to adapt a few changes and see if that fixes the issue.

```py
#shpin is an input parameter (string)
#rules is an input parameter (list)

scratch = "D:/data"

#Create PGDB and feature dataset for topology and new feature class
gdb = arcpy.CreatePersonalGDB_management(scratch, "tempGDB", "CURRENT")
dataset = arcpy.CreateFeatureDataset_management(gdb, "streets", arcpy.Describe(shpin).spatialReference)

#Import feature class to feature dataset
fclass = arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion(shpin, dataset, "temporary")

#Create topology and add recently imported FC
topology = arcpy.CreateTopology_management(dataset, "topology", "#")
arcpy.AddFeatureClassToTopology_management(topology, fclass, "1", "1")

#Iterate through list of rules and add each
[arcpy.AddRuleToTopology_management(topology, "{0} (Line)".format(rule),
                                    fclass, "", "", "") for rule in rules]

arcpy.ValidateTopology_management(topology, "Full_Extent")
```