# Setting topology rules to connect short lines aross complex intersections

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, intersection, topology, arcgis-10.7

I have a polyline SHP with a bunch of very short lines (less than one meter length).

*Is there an automated way to force the short lines to connect to a neighboring line at complex intersections*?

In the example below, I'd want the highlighted line to connect with the line on the same trend (i.e., northeast to southwest; north is up). Using ArcMap 10.7 Advanced License. I will ultimately need to do this for a few dozen SHP files, and each has thousands of lines in it (so, I'll roll the solution into ArcPy).

[image]

Comment: use geodatabase (can merge the shapefles) then use the topology ruleshttps://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/editing-topology/geodatabase-topology-rules-and-topology-error-fixes.htm#GUID-2154EDB0-E9C2-4B76-8F8D-94B81FE13D7B then acpy can used to automate https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/94112/adding-rules-to-topology-with-arcpy-getting-error-000714

Comment: whats the typical gap distance between your end of short line to the line you want to snap to? metres, kilometres?

Comment: You obviously shown us the sum total of 1 example, so assuming the rest of your data is the same (???) then have a look at the [extend line](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/editing-toolbox/extend-line.htm#) tool as a potential solution?

Comment: Probably not what you're looking for, but here is a method using postgis topology: http://blog.mathieu-leplatre.info/use-postgis-topologies-to-clean-up-road-networks.html

Comment: is there a common attribute between the two lines you want to connect? (i.e. ID number, name).